# How to receive Android Volley's JsonObjectRequest in jsp?

Tags: android, jsp, android-volley

I am trying to send some information from Android device to a database using the Volley library. The information is received on the server by jsp script, and upon receiving I need to extract the values and use a Java Bean to update the database. 
I have used a JSONObject as shown in my jsp code but I end up with a symbol not found error". Can someone please point to where I am going wrong or give an example that uses volley with jsp.

Java code

```
private void registerMember(final String IDNo, final String NHIFNo, final String Email, final String MobileNo, final String Password, final String ConfPassword){
            //startActivity(new Intent(Register.this,LoginActivity.class));

        pDialog.show();

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Links.register, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error == null || error.networkResponse == null) {
                    return;
                }

                String body="";
                //get status code here
                final String statusCode = String.valueOf(error.networkResponse.statusCode);
                //get response body and parse with appropriate encoding
                try {
                    body = new String(error.networkResponse.data,"UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // exception
                }

                Log.d(TAG2, body+" code "+statusCode);
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                params.put("IDNo", IDNo);
                params.put("NHIFNo", NHIFNo);
                params.put("Email", Email);
                params.put("MobileNo", MobileNo);
                params.put("Password", Password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);
        }
```

Then JSP code

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>
<jsp:useBean id="sessionBean" scope="session" class="com.ngenx.edms.SessionBean"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:useBean id="mailBean" scope="session" class="com.ngenx.edms.Mail.EMailBean"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:useBean id="registryBean" scope="session" class="com.ngenx.edms.Registry.RegistryBean"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:useBean id="applicationLevelBean" scope="session" class="com.ngenx.edms.ApplicationLevel"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:useBean id="systemPropertiesBean" scope="application" class="com.ngenx.edms.System.SystemPropertiesBean"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:useBean id="membersBean" scope="session" class="com.ngenx.ehmis.Members.MembersBean"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:useBean id="registerMember" scope="session" class="com.ngenx.Android.RegisterMember"></jsp:useBean>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.text.*"%>
<%@page import="com.oreilly.servlet.*"%>
<%@page import="com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.*"%>
<%@page import="org.json.JSONObject.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%
       try{
             String idNo = ""; 
             String nfNo = "";
             String email = ""; 
             String mobileNo = "";
             String password = "";       
            // this parses the json
            System.out.println("REQ_PARAM "+request.getParameter("params"));

            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(request.getParameter("params")); 
            Iterator it = jObj.keys(); //gets all the keys

            while(it.hasNext())
            {
                 String key = it.next(); // get key

                if(key.equals("IDNo")){
                    idNo=jObj.get(key);
                }else if(key.equals("NFNo")){
                    nfNo=jObj.get(key);
                }else if(key.equals("Email")){
                    email=jObj.get(key);
                }else if(key.equals("MobileNo")){
                    mobileNo=jObj.get(key);
                }else if(key.equals("Password")){
                    password=jObj.get(key);
                }
            }//end of while

             if(registerMember.memberRegistration(idNo,nhNo,email,mobileNo,password)){
                     JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                     json.put("Registering", "Successful");
                     response.setContentType("application/json");
                     response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
             }
     }catch(Exception e){
         out.print("A general error was realised.<br>"+e.getMessage());
         action = "register";
     }

%>
```

Server log trace

```
PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /registerMember.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class org.apache.jsp.registerMember_jsp

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /registerMember.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class org.apache.jsp.registerMember_jsp

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /registerMember.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /registerMember.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class org.apache.jsp.registerMember_jsp

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /registerMember.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class org.apache.jsp.registerMember_jsp

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /registerMember.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable action
  location: class org.apache.jsp.registerMember_jsp


    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:299)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:392)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:460)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]
```

Comment: JSONObject class is not found did you import the library?

Comment: and Second thing you are posting value as a key value pair in form of map

Comment: Yes, the library is in WEB-INF folder

Comment: what value did you get at the line of ` System.out.println("REQ_PARAM "+request.getParameter("params"));`

Comment: that line doesn't even execute, it can't be found in the trace log...seems like the whole scriptlet is not executing

Comment: comment this line `<%@page import="org.json.JSONObject.*"%>`  and also comment out the code below `System.out.println("REQ_PARAM "+request.getParameter("params"));`  and try

Comment: The error still persists